# Select data based on few consideration

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to select data based on the below considerations -

[image: CONSIDERATION IMAGE]

Now we have two tables -

TABLE 1 -

| DLR_ID | CALL_ID | VEHICLE | PLAN_NO | CALL_STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | AA | 5 | Generated |
| 2 | 12 | AA | 5 | Generated |
| 1 | 13 | AA | 10 | Generated |
| 2 | 14 | AA | 10 | Not Generated |
| 1 | 15 | BB | 5 | Generated |
| 1 | 16 | BB | 10 | Generated |
| 2 | 17 | CC | 5 | Not Generated |
| 3 | 18 | CC | 5 | Generated |
| 1 | 19 | DD | 5 | Not Generated |
| 4 | 20 | DD | 5 | Not Generated |
| 3 | 21 | EE | 5 | Generated |
| 2 | 22 | FF | 10 | Generated |
| 4 | 23 | FF | 10 | Generated |
| 5 | 24 | GG | 20 | Generated |
| 6 | 25 | GG | 20 | Generated |

TABLE 2 -

| DLR_ID | CALL_ID | CALL_COUNT | CALL_RESULT_STATUS | CALL_DATE(DD/MM/YYYY) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 1 | Continue | 16/03/2021 |
| 1 | 11 | 2 | Give-up | 20/03/2021 |
| 2 | 12 | 1 | Completed | 15/03/2021 |
| 1 | 13 | 1 | Continue | 01/04/2021 |
| 1 | 15 | 1 | Completed | 21/02/2021 |
| 1 | 16 | 1 | Give-up | 20/03/2021 |
| 3 | 18 | 1 | Continue | 21/05/2021 |
| 3 | 21 | 1 | Give-up | 24/04/2021 |
| 2 | 22 | 1 | Completed | 19/03/2021 |
| 4 | 23 | 1 | Completed | 03/05/2021 |
| 5 | 24 | 1 | Continue | 11/02/2021 |
| 5 | 24 | 2 | Completed | 11/05/2021 |
| 6 | 25 | 1 | Continue | 10/02/2021 |
| 6 | 25 | 2 | Continue | 21/02/2021 |
| 6 | 25 | 3 | Continue | 21/04/2021 |

OUTPUT -

| DLR_ID | VEHICLE | PLAN_NO | CALL_STATUS | CALL_ID | CALL_DATE | CALL_RESULT_STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA | 5 | Generated | 12 | 15/03/2021 | Completed |
| 2 | AA | 5 | Generated | 12 | 15/03/2021 | Completed |
| 1 | AA | 10 | Generated | 13 | 01/04/2021 | Continue |
| 2 | AA | 10 | Not Generated | 13 | 01/04/2021 | Continue |
| 1 | BB | 5 | Generated | 15 | 21/02/2021 | Completed |
| 1 | BB | 10 | Generated | 15 | 21/02/2021 | Completed |
| 2 | CC | 5 | Not Generated | 18 | 21/05/2021 | Continue |
| 3 | CC | 5 | Generated | 18 | 21/05/2021 | Continue |
| 1 | DD | 5 | Not Generated |  |  |  |
| 4 | DD | 5 | Not Generated |  |  |  |
| 3 | EE | 5 | Generated | 21 | 21/04/2021 | Give-up |
| 2 | FF | 10 | Generated | 23 | 03/05/2021 | Completed |
| 4 | FF | 10 | Generated | 23 | 03/05/2021 | Completed |
| 5 | GG | 20 | Generated | 24 | 11/05/2021 | Completed |
| 6 | GG | 20 | Generated | 24 | 11/05/2021 | Completed |

Kindly help me out in extracting the building oracle query to extract the data like mentioned in OUTPUT table.

Code which I was trying is -

```
SELECT t1.DLR_id, t1.VEHICLE,t1.PLAN_NO,t1.CALL_STATUS,
NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN t1.CALL_STATUS='Generated' and t2.CALL_RESULT_STATUS = 'Completed' THEN t2.CALL_ID END),
MAX(CASE WHEN t1.CALL_STATUS!='Generated' and t2.CALL_RESULT_STATUS != 'Completed' THEN t2.CALL_ID  END)) as CALL_ID  
FROM Table1 t1  
left JOIN Table2 t2    
ON t1.DLR_ID=t2.DLR_ID 
and t2.call_id = t1.call_id     
group by T1.DLR_ID,t1.VEHICLE,t1.PLAN_NO,
T1.CALL_STATUS     
order by t1.VEHICLE,t1.plan_no,t1.dlr_id
```

Comment: Please, provide your current code and describe what is wrong with it. SO is not a codewriting service to compose the code for you from scratch.

Comment: I was not able to achieve my result. I tried the below code -

SELECT 
t1.DLR_id, 
t1.VEHICLE,
t1.PLAN_NO,
t1.CALL_STATUS,
NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN t1.CALL_STATUS='Generated' 
and t2.CALL_RESULT_STATUS = 'Completed' THEN t2.CALL_ID END),MAX(CASE WHEN t1.CALL_STATUS!='Generated' 
and t2.CALL_RESULT_STATUS != 'Completed' THEN t2.CALL_ID  END)) as CALL_ID
  FROM Table1 t1
  left JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.DLR_ID=t2.DLR_ID and t2.call_id = t1.call_id 
    group by T1.DLR_ID,t1.VEHICLE,t1.PLAN_NO,T1.CALL_STATUS
     order by t1.VEHICLE,t1.plan_no,t1.dlr_id

Comment: Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67900122/edit) your original question and add it here.

Comment: Done. I am not asking you to write the code from scratch. Just guide me in some way so that I should achieve the OUTPUT.